# Why do we distinguish between row rank and column rank

Tags: linear-algebra

We know from linear algebra that the row rank is equal to the column rank. However, I keep seeing authors specifying either row or column rank in the literature. For example, I just came across a paper that advocates the use of the pseudoinverse because "A may not have full row rank". Are there cases where it matters whether a matrix has full row rank as compared to column rank? Why not just say rank?

Comment: Full row rank means that the rank is the same as the number of rows. Full rank means that the matrix has maximum possible rank, but there may be more rows than columns, and in that case a full rank matrix still won't have full row rank. Full row rank is a more specific description. It can be important to distinguish whether the rows or the columns of the matrix are linearly independent, and that's why the term is useful.

Comment: If $A$ is a rectangular matrix having more columns than rows then $A$ can have full row rank but it cannot have full column rank.